# Converting IDL to TS

Tags: anchor, solana-program, spl-token, spl-token-program

I have an IDL here and I am trying to convert a function, but it is giving me errors. I am trying to use it on the browser. Can you please help as this is urgent? Thanks.

IDL:

```
    {
  "name": "initPurchase",
  "accounts": [
    {
      "name": "buyer",
      "isMut": true,
      "isSigner": true
    },
    {
      "name": "item",
      "isMut": true,
      "isSigner": false
    },
    {
      "name": "merchant",
      "isMut": false,
      "isSigner": false
    },
    {
      "name": "transaction",
      "isMut": true,
      "isSigner": false
    },
    {
      "name": "vault",
      "isMut": true,
      "isSigner": false
    },
    {
      "name": "buyerWallet",
      "isMut": true,
      "isSigner": false
    },
    {
      "name": "mint",
      "isMut": false,
      "isSigner": false
    },
    {
      "name": "tokenProgram",
      "isMut": false,
      "isSigner": false
    },
    {
      "name": "systemProgram",
      "isMut": false,
      "isSigner": false
    },
    {
      "name": "rent",
      "isMut": false,
      "isSigner": false
    }
  ],
  "args": [
    {
      "name": "amount",
      "type": "u64"
    }
  ]
},
```

My code:

```
const purchaseInitiation = await this.program.methods
  .initPurchase(itemAmountBN)
  .accounts({
    //@ts-ignore
    buyer: this.userPubKey,
    item: itemPDA,
    merchant: merchantPDA,
    transaction: transactionPDA,
    vault: vaultPDA,
    //@ts-ignore
    buyerWallet: this.userPubKey,
    mint: itemCurrencyMintAddress,
  })
  .transaction();

const transactionSignature =
  await this.sendAndConfirmTransactionWithAnchorWallet(purchaseInitiation);
```

Is there anything I am missing, because I keep getting this error:

```
index.browser.esm.js?156f:7826 Uncaught (in promise) Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0xbbf
at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (index.browser.esm.js?156f:7826:1)
at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (index.browser.esm.js?156f:7783:1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The error you got is indicating that one of the accounts provided to the instruction is owned by a different program than the one handling it.

This is most likely a seeding issue for one or more of the PDAs. Check to make sure that:

1. The program was deployed to the current address with the correct `declare_id` value
2. The program ID used in the PDA derivation function calls matches that.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `anchor build`, there's a TS version of the IDL in the target folder

However, the error you are getting is:

`#[msg("The given account is owned by a different program than expected")]`

https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/lang/src/error.rs#L154

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. Though I'm not sure what I should be doing to fix the problem. There are some inputs that I missed but I'm not sure if they matter.